# Почему при включении аппаратного ускорения отображение svg файла становится размытым?

Tags: android, svg, path, assets

Почему происходит размытие элемента **path** в то время как **rectangle** и **circle** без размытия? Я нашёл решение в виде отключения аппаратного ускорения (заменой на программное), но мне хотелось бы оставить аппаратное ускорение для данного View и избавиться от размытия.

```
android:layerType="hardware" // аппаратное
android:layerType="software" // программное
```

В gradle важная строчка указана

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

Вот код загрузки изображения SVG формата из Assets.

```
// https://github.com/Pixplicity/sharp          
Sharp sharp = Sharp.loadAsset(getAssets(), "drawing.svg"); 
Drawable drawable = sharp.getDrawable();
view = findViewById(R.id.photo_view); //ImageView
view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Прошу не предлагать импорт Vector asset в Drawable ресурсы. Мне это не подходит. В моём приложении планируется сотня небольших векторных изображений, которые я планирую размещать в папке assets.

Проблема одинаково выглядит как на эмуляторе так и на реальных устройствах.

```
android:layerType="hardware" // аппаратное
```

[image: android:layerType="hardware"]

```
android:layerType="software" // программное
```

[image: android:layerType="software"]

Answer (score 3):

Несколько дней мучился меняя библиотеки для работы с SVG. Но как это обычно бывает, ответ на собственный вопрос находится сразу же после того как задашь вопрос на стэковерфлоу )

**Для назначения изображения нужно было использовать метод into():**

```
view = findViewById(R.id.photo_view); //ImageView 
Sharp.loadAsset(getAssets(), "drawing.svg")
        .into(view);
```

Всем спасибо! Надеюсь этот вопрос поможет кому нибудь в будущем ) Размытие исчезло во всех режимах **android:layerType**.

*P.S. Всё равно загадка остаётся неразгаданной, откуда берётся размытие и почему оно возникает только на path элементах svg файла*

Comment: `Sharp.into()` вызывает `Sharp.prepareView()`  который в свою очередь делает `view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`. То есть просто отключает программное ускорение. Вы не ответили, ни на свой вопрос "почему появилось размытие", ни нашли решение "хотелось бы оставить аппаратное ускорение". Я ответил "почему появилось размытие", но вот как избавиться от размытия в вашем случае к сожалению не знаю.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Я проверил, всё именно так как вы написали. 
Придётся с этим жить. )

Answer (score 1):

Для `path` даже при `android:layerType="hardware"` все линии сначала будут переведены с помощью CPU в растовое изображение, и только потом оно передается в GPU. И если после этого, изображению будет необходимо масштабирование, у `path` будет растягиваться/сжиматься растр, в отличии от примитивных фигур.

Вот `line` например будет рисоваться нормально.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но на мой вопрос вы не ответили. И круг и прямоугольник тоже переводились в растровое изображение, но размытия не получили. Размытие получает только элемент path. Мой вопрос был в том почему появилось размытие и как от него избавиться при аппаратном ускорении.

Comment: И даже если так, откуда должно появится размытие?

Comment: Все фигуры кроме path будут нарисованы именно GPU. А вместо path GPU получит растр, который уже сама растянет.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, видимо размер изображения отличается от используемых координат, и изображение приходиться масштабировать.